Не могу добавить кнопку на экран помогите пожалуйста. Вот такая ошибка появляется:
Код:
# Imports
import pygame
import time
import sys
import pygame_light2d as pl2d
from pygame_light2d import LightingEngine, PointLight

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Create lights engine with the lightmap downscaled by 2.5
screen_res = (1280, 720)
lights_engine = LightingEngine(
    screen_res=screen_res,
    native_res=screen_res,
    lightmap_res=(int(screen_res[0] / 2.5), int(screen_res[1] / 2.5))
)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_res)

    введите сюда код

# Initialize the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the ambient light
lights_engine.set_ambient(0, 0, 0, 128)

# Load the background image
tex_background = lights_engine.load_texture('assets/FON.jpg')

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
button_rect = pygame.Rect(565, 335, 150, 50)

# Set the maximum luminosity
lights_engine.max_luminosity = 1

# Create a point light
light_radius = 600
light_pow = 1.0
light = PointLight(position=(100, 100), power=light_pow, radius=light_radius)
light.set_color(255, 255, 255, 255)  # Set a fixed white color for the light

# Add the point light to the engine
lights_engine.lights.append(light)

# Function to draw the button
def draw_button(surface):
    # Check if the mouse is hovering over the button
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        color = (200, 200, 200)  # Lighter gray
    else:
        color = (255, 255, 255)  # White

    # Draw the button and text
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, button_rect)
    text = font.render("Start", True, (0, 0, 0))
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=button_rect.center)
    surface.blit(text, text_rect)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # Tick the clock at 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Move the light to the mouse pointer's position
    light.position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Clear the background with black color
    lights_engine.clear(0, 0, 0)

    # Draw background image
    lights_engine.render_texture(
        tex_background, pl2d.BACKGROUND,
        pygame.Rect(0, 0, screen_res[0], screen_res[1]),
        pygame.Rect(0, 0, tex_background.width, tex_background.height))

    # Render the lighting
    lights_engine.render()

    # Get the rendered frame as a texture
    frame_texture = lights_engine.get_texture()
    frame_surface = pygame.image.fromstring(frame_texture.to_bytes(), screen_res, 'RGBA')

    # Blit the lighting frame onto the screen
    screen.blit(frame_surface, (0, 0))

    # Draw the button on top of the lighting
    draw_button(screen)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Process events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for quit event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # Check for mouse button click
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print("Button clicked!")

Ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dimitry\PycharmProjects\Game\interface1.py", line 28, in <module>
    tex_background = lights_engine.load_texture('assets/FON.jpg')
  File "C:\Users\Dimitry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pygame_light2d\engine.py", line 279, in load_texture
    return self._graphics.load_texture(path)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Dimitry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pygame_render\engine.py", line 168, in load_texture
    return self.surface_to_texture(img)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Dimitry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pygame_render\engine.py", line 152, in surface_to_texture
    tex = self._ctx.texture(sfc.get_size(), components=4, data=img_data)
  File "C:\Users\Dimitry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\moderngl\__init__.py", line 1833, in texture
    res.mglo, res._glo = self.mglo.texture(
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        size, components, data, samples, alignment, dtype, internal_format or 0, renderbuffer
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
    ^
_moderngl.Error: cannot create texture

